# Is there a language setting for the HERE autosuggest endpoint?

Tags: here-api

I am using the HERE autosuggest to search for places.
Somehow I get a different place ressorce link depending on the app credentials used in the request.

My problem is that the result I receive witm my app ID points to a resource link in local language while the HERE demo app result is in english.(see example below)
I would also like to always get the results in my app in english and with roman characters.

Is there a setting or parameter that I need to use to always retrieve the result in english?

**My App:**

https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?q=Dubai&result_types=address&Geolocation=geo%3A48.2076%2C16.3914&app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx

the response contains a resource link: https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/here:cm:namedplace:21399080?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx. By accessing this link the response has the address in local language:
"location":{"position":[25.26951,55.30884],"address":{"text":"دبي
الإمارات العربية المتحدة","city":"دبي","county":"دبي","country":"الإمارات العربية المتحدة","countryCode":"ARE"}

**Demo App:**

https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?q=Dubai&result_types=address&Geolocation=geo%3A48.2076%2C16.3914&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg#

response resource link: https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPUR1YmFpO2xhbmc9ZW47bGF0PTI1LjI2OTUyO2xvbj01NS4zMDg4NTtjaXR5PUR1YmFpO2NvdW50cnk9QVJFO2NvdW50eT1EdWJhaTtjYXRlZ29yeUlkPWNpdHktdG93bi12aWxsYWdlO3NvdXJjZVN5c3RlbT1pbnRlcm5hbDtwZHNDYXRlZ29yeUlkPTkwMC05MTAwLTAwMDA;context=Zmxvdy1pZD1iN2E5YzNmYS1mMGJmLTU1YjAtYTQ3MC1lMWJlMjM1YTQ5YzNfMTYwNzk1NTQ2MjkzNV84ODUxXzE2MzgmYmJveD01NS4wMzY0MyUyQzI0LjkxODg0JTJDNTUuNTY0MTUlMkMyNS4zMjc4MyZyYW5rPTA?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

with the response:
{"position":[25.26952,55.30885],"address":{"text":"Dubai<br/>United Arab Emirates","city":"Dubai","county":"Dubai","country":"United Arab Emirates","countryCode":"ARE"}

Thanks for your help
Tom

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation , the result language depends on the Accept-Language header.(https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/localization.html)

Maybe the header is being set in your app to Arabic hence the results are in Arabic ? Try explicitly setting the header to English.